# Reference on relating Post systems to string rewriting systems and formal grammars?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, reference-request, term-rewriting

[wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system#String_rewriting_systems,_type-0_formal_grammars):

> Every Post canonical system can be reduced to a string rewriting system (semi-Thue system). [...]
>
> It has been proved that any Post canonical system is reducible to such a substitution system, which, as a formal grammar, is also called a phrase-structure grammar, or a type-0 grammar in the Chomsky hierarchy.

And on [a different page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-Thue_system#Connections_with_other_notions) it says:

> A semi-Thue system is also a special type of Post canonical system, but every Post canonical system can also be reduced to an SRS.

I have not been able to find a good explanation of these statements.

**Is there a good reference that shows how to do conversions between these notions?**